# Adding A Custom Property To Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework for the first time and want to know if the following is possible - I have generated my classes from the DB, and have one called Category.

Obviously it has all my fields in the table (ID, CategoryName, SortOrder etc..) but I want to know if I can add a custom property which is not in the table, but is actually the result of a custom method.

I want to add a new property called 'CategoryURL' which is basically the 'CategoryName' property run through a custom method and returns a hyphenated string.

My initial thought is inheriting from the generated Category class and creating something like this inside?

```
public string CategoryURL 
{
    get{ return MyCustomMethod(this.CategoryName) }
}
```

Is this the correct approach? And will 'this.CategoryName' work as I think it should? Basically the end result is when I return a list of 'Category' I want this to be part of the class so I can use it in my foreach loop.

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you should use a [`partial`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_class) class:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public string CategoryURL  
    { 
        get{ return MyCustomMethod(this.CategoryName); } 
    } 
}
```

This way `this.CategoryName` will work just as expected.

This works because the classes generated by the entity framework code generator also generates `partial` classes. It also means that you can safely re-generate the classes from the database without affecting the partial classes that you have defined yourself.

Comment: That's clever!  In a way, it's sort of spooky because it seems *too* clever.  Do we have any reason to believe that Microsoft might break this in a future EF release?  I suppose I should worry too much as this answer is nearly four years old and it just worked for me!

Comment: @VivianRiver "Do we have any reason to believe that Microsoft might break this in a future EF release?" - `partial`-classes are a C# thing and have nothing to do with Entity Framework. Also, it's fundamental to how entity classes in EF work, including the latest versions of EF Core: though EF Core's scaffolding scripts and templates (for generating entity types from an existing database design) are rather _anemic_ so I always recommend using this instead: https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator

Answer (score 17):

You should add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the property

Comment: I'd like to add that the `[NotMapped]` attribute is only needed for properties with `get` and `set`. If you have a readonly property (e.g. a computed property with no `set`) then `[NotMapped]` is unnecessary.