# Access custom property in Entity Class

Tags: entity-framework, custom-attributes, partial-classes

I'm new to Entity Framework 4.1, and I have pretty much the same problem as this guy:
[Adding A Custom Property To Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967453/adding-a-custom-property-to-entity-framework)

However, when I add a custom read-only property to my Entity using partial classes, I'm unable to access it as a property.

```
//Auto-generated Entity Class EntityModel.cs
public partial class Model
{
  public string foo {get; set;}
  public string bar {get; set;}
}

//Custom class  EntityModelCustom.cs
public partial class Model
{
   public string baz
   {
      get
      {
       return string.Format("{0}+{1}", this.foo, this.bar);
      }
   }
}
```

In my code, when I try to obtain property

```
Model m = new Model();
```

m.foo and m.bar are accessible. But I can't access m.baz which is what I want :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both of your definitions are in the same namespace. usually, this is the cause of not seeing the other property.

Comment: They're both in the same namespace.

Comment: They must also be in the same assembly.