# How we can add new properties to entity framework models with mef extensions/plugins?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, mef

I am writing an asp.net mvc application with MEF to extending the application features, my data access is created by entity framework. In my scenario i must have ability to extend entity framework models with plugins that retrived with mef.

Each plugin may have their own properties to be added to the specified model/models. I have searched and can't find much information on the issue, if any one has any idea pleas help me to solve it.

The question in address: [Adding A Custom Property To Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967453/adding-a-custom-property-to-entity-framework) is very different from my question, i want to any property that added to model be stored in (and retrive from) the database. And, new properties in my scenario must added in run time and must be retrived with MEF in a plugin.